# Query 2008r2 Hyper-V for VMs and their disk info

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have hyper V 2008r2. I need to run script from another server. script needs to query for all hosted vm's, with their attached network (at the hyper v level), disk type and path and snapshot location. 2008 doesn't support power shell cmdlets. I been playing around with - `-Class Msvm_ImageManagementService` `.GetVirtualHardDiskInfo`. Just cannot make it work. i don't really have a sample script so far to show you as nothing i try works. I can so far only get the vms `Get-WMIObject -Class Msvm_ComputerSystem -Namespace "root\virtualization" -ComputerName "host"| Select-Object ElementName`. checked around all over google cannot really find a place to begin. Thanks for you help.

Comment: check it you should import hyper-v module and then use commands in module for your problem [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx)

Comment: i tired this.... if i run command on hyperv2012 to query servers on hyperv2008 i get error - [    get-vm : The Hyper-V role is not installed on the destination host. Add the Hyper-V role on that host and then run this cmdlet again.   ]

Comment: i think you send command to server can not recognize go to server import hyper-v module and try to do someting like `Get-VM` if not work upgrade your powershell to 4.0 and try again

Answer (score 0):

you have to import modules from here. `https://pshyperv.codeplex.com` then you will have limited cmdlets.... cant find any other way around it.